# Google Sheet уровни защиты и доступа к диапазонам ячеек (все, определенные, на основе email)

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Имеется этот **Google Sheet** :
[image]

***SourceSheet** (источник) доступен: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3nQZ1ZS0Y9zUv1ZfdjQlWIVHSqf-wF4neNDksCse6Y/edit?usp=drive_link)*

---

Правила защиты ячеек:

- Диапазоны **B2:B10** и **B13:B21** могут редактировать все.
- Диапазоны **D2:D10** и **F2:F10** могут редактировать только пользователи, указанные в учетной записи по электронной почте.
- Все остальные оставшиеся ячейки защищены и никто не может их редактировать.

---

Код:

```
function setEditPermissions() {
  var sheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3nQZ1ZS0Y9zUv1ZfdjQlWIVHSqf-wF4neNDksCse6Y/edit?usp=drive_link';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';

  protectAllCells(sheetUrl, sheetName )
  setEditable(sheetUrl, sheetName)
  setEmailAccess(sheetUrl, sheetName) 
}


function protectAllCells(sheetUrl, sheetName ) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Защищаем все ячейки на листе
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Защита всего листа');

  // Устанавливаем права доступа на редактирование
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
}



function setEditable(sheetUrl, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var editableRanges = ['B2:B10', 'B13:B21'];

 editableRanges.forEach(function(rangeStr) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeStr);
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + rangeStr);
    protection.remove();
  });
}


function setEmailAccess(sheetUrl, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Диапазоны, которые нужно защитить
  var rangesToProtect = ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10'];

  // Пользователи, которым разрешено редактировать диапазоны
  var allowedUsers = ['aitbayev.us@gmail.com'];

  rangesToProtect.forEach(function(rangeStr) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeStr);
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + rangeStr);
    // Удаляем все предыдущие редакторы
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    // Запрещаем редактирование всем, кроме указанных пользователей
    protection.addEditors(allowedUsers);
    // Разрешаем только указанным пользователям редактировать
    //protection.setWarningOnly(true);
  });
}
```

---

Первый шаг (защита листа работает с функцией **ProtectAllCells** ). Следующие 2 шага (функции: **setEditable**, **setEmailAccess** ) не сработали. Но логика кажется верной.

Можно ли это реализовать с помощью Google Apps Script и Google Sheets по кодам?

Answer (score 0):

А что именно не сработало?
Насколько позволяет мне судить мой опыт работы со скриптами, при каждом вызове функции protect() накладывается защита. Эту проблему я решила просто заранее определив в отдельную переменную диапазоны с вызовом функции protect() и уже работала с этой переменной.
В вашем случае примерно так:
var protectRange=sheet.getRange(rangeStr).protect()

и уже потом:
protectRange.removeEditors(protectRange.getEditors())
protectRange.addEditors('здесь нужно указать почту редактора или массив из почт')

Таким образом вы один раз защитите диапазон и потом будете просто удалять редакторов при добавлении пользователей.